# Jenkins NUnit report file not found

Tags: c#, testing, jenkins, nunit, automated-tests

I run my NUnit tests on Jenkins but every time build step fails and i get this text:

*Recording NUnit tests results
FATAL: No NUnit test report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Publish NUnit test result report' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE*

It is actually caused by tests report files that cannot be found.

I added *"Publish Nunit test result report"* post-build action:
**"%WORKSPACE%\TestResults*.xml"**

however jenkins cannot find it.

I checked if report file is created in my workspace and actually **it is created in proper place** so there should not be problem to read it.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think the NUnit plugin doesn't support environment variables in the file path. However, if the file is relative to the workspace, you should be able to omit %WORKSPACE%.

Comment: I even tried with absolute path but it is still not working

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by change file destination from absolute path `C:\Build\TestResults\MyTest.xml` to relative `TestResults\MyTest.xml`.

I think Nunit plugin use relative path. You can go into the tab `Workspace` in your job and find this xml, then just copy path with your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try?

```
nunit testResultsPattern: 'TestResults.xml'
```

(without asterisk character)
By default nunit xml is saved in the same directory as your Jenkins build project.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative,

I am successfully using **NUnit3** with the **Jenkins NUnit plugin**, by **running** the tests using a **command line** that includes: `format=nunit2`

Read more [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32999)